# Is my use of Promises in an asynchronous function correct?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I'm finally trying to get to grips with **Promises**, one of the newer and more mysterious corners of **JavaScript**. The following is a problem I came across in a technical test, and which seems to get to the heart of what I don't understand about Promises.

The problem is as follows:

- You have a **predefined class** called `Service`, with the following methods:

  - `generate()` - which generates a random number between 0 and 100.
  - `guess(yourGuess)` - which takes a given guess for the random number, and returns a Promise. This Promise, in turn will do one of two things within **100 ms**:

    - If the guess is correct, the Promise will be resolved, with the guess corresponding to that Promise as its first argument.
    - If the guess is incorrect, the Promise will be rejected.
  - `submit(yourGuess)` - which submits a guess you believe is correct.
- You have to write an **asynchronous** function, `main()`, which will:

  - Generate a random number using a `Service` object.
  - Submit a correct guess to the same object **within 400 ms**.
  - Any rejected Promises have to be caught.

This is my code:

```js
const MAX_NUMBER = 100;

async function main()
{
    const service = new Service();
    let guessInPromise;

    service.generate();

    for(let i = 0; i <= MAX_NUMBER; i++)
    {
        service.guess(i)
            .then(guessInPromise => service.submit(guessInPromise));
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }

    return service;
}
```

**Would my code get the job done? Is there anything I've obviously misunderstood about Promises and asynchronous functions?**

Comment: does `generate()` or `guess()` return Promise objects?

Comment: `const guessInPromise;` makes no sense, as you do not give it an initial value and cannot give it a value later.

Comment: I think the trick here is to map all possible guesses to promises using `Service.guess(...)` and then wait for [`Promise.any()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any).

Comment: @crashmstr in fact, it should just error - declaring a const without assignment is meaningless and a forbidden syntax.

Comment: This code would function, yet there are some oddities. Why return `service`? Wouldn't it make sense to log "The correct number was X". Instead of a whole bunch of floating promises, it'd be best to return a result once you have a correct guess. Your code currently immediately returns the service object. Edit: I see Yoshi beat me to it.

Comment: I would recommend you check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1260204

Comment: @AlwaysLearning As I mentioned above, `guess()` returns a Promise. `generate()` returns nothing.

Comment: @VLAZ Apologies. That should be a `let`. I'll amend my question.

Comment: @samthecodingman Yeah, I thought the `return service;` thing was weird too. However, the problem came with some code and then an `// Insert your code here` comment, and the return statement was part of the original code, which you **weren't** supposed to alter.

Comment: @Yoshi If you were to flesh that comment out into an answer, and if you could assure me that your code would `submit()` a correct guess within 400 ms, I would definitely accept that answer.

Comment: @TomHosker ah, if that's the case then it's also expecting you to be using `async`/`await` syntax in your solution. In regards to `guessInPromise`, it's never set, even inside the callback you are passing to `then()`. Just delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your requirements, I'd assume the task is to *somehow* guess the correct answer in 400ms whereas each guess takes 100ms. A very simple solution here would be to do all guesses in *parallel* and only wait for the first to be resolved.

This would work because `Service.guess` is described to only resolve it's returned promise for valid guesses (others will be rejected).

Very helpful here would be: [`Promise.any`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any)

And an example could be:

```js
// very simple mock implementation for the described Service class
class Service
{
  value = null;

  generate() {
    this.value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
  }

  guess(yourGuess) {
    return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
          yourGuess === this.value ? resolve(yourGuess) : reject()
      }, 100);
    }));
  }

  submit(yourGuess) {
    return yourGuess === this.value;
  }
}

const MAX_NUMBER = 100;

(async function main() {
  const service = new Service();

  service.generate();

  try {
    // await first resolved guess
    const assumedCorrect = await Promise.any(
      // map 0 ... 100 to service.guess(...)
      Array.from({length: MAX_NUMBER + 1}).map((_, i) => service.guess(i))
    );

    console.log(
      assumedCorrect,
      service.submit(assumedCorrect)
    );
  }
  catch {
    console.log('No guess was correct... :(');
  }
})();
```

Comment: Apologies. One thing I forgot to mention is that the question specifies that any rejected Promises - `guess()` will reject if the guess in question is incorrect - have to be **caught**. Would sticking a `.catch()` after the `.any()` do the trick?

Comment: Ah ok, give me a moment. Though, given how `Promise.any` works, only if no guess is correct it would be rejected. So which one should be caught?

Comment: I added a simple try/catch block. Though you would need to reduce `MAX_NUMBER` and try a few times, to actually trigger the catch (for the case no valid guess was made).